# How to have real full screen with Civilization in DOSBox?

Tags: dosbox, civilization

My screen have a resolution of 1366x768. When I play Civilization (version 1), I got the image in a resolution of 640x400 in the middle of the screen, the rest being black. Instead, when I play Orion, the image occupies all screen.

Which DOSBox option should I change to have the same with Civilization?

Comment: try Sid Meier's Civilization 1.2 for Windows, released for Windows 3.11 in 1991; it still runs natively on Windows 7, supporting windows up to 1600 x 900 px in size

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You probably will need to change the [scaler](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Scaler) parameter - this controls how the "classic" DOS resolution is upscaled to fill the higher resolution of today's monitors.  The various types represent the algorithm used to upscale the image, and the "2x" or "3x" control how much upscaling should be applied.

You may also have to change [fullresolution](http://www.dosbox.com/wiki/Dosbox.conf), which does additional scaling to match your monitor's resolution.

Comment: scaler=normal3x does the trick (however, it slow thing down).

Answer (score 2):

Try using

```
fullresolution=1366x768
output=overlay
scaler=normal2x
```

Now try to play it fullscreen.

Answer (score 0):

You can also try to press the fullscreen key combination, usually Alt+Enter. If it still doesn't work, check first that you have the dosbox window grabbed (Ctrl+F10).